# how to define $x^\sqrt 2$?

Tags: exponentiation

Can anyone please tell me how to define $x^\sqrt 2$ ?

If it was $x^2$ or $x ^ \frac{1}{2}$, we could have said that  $x^2$ means $x \times x$ and $x ^ \frac{1}{2}$ means a number y such that $y^2 = x$.

But  how to define $x^\sqrt 2$ ?

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: $e^{\sqrt2\ln x}$?

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1272546/42969

Comment: I think it is poor practice to think of $x^a$ as $x\times x$ $a$ times (or the inverse of this). What does $e^x$ mean in that case? What about $x^i$? Think of the exponential function as a special function that satisfies the property $a^x a^y=a^{x+y}$. Then for integer exponents it follows that the exponential function is repeated multiplication. But you should think of this as a special case of the exponential function and not the other way round.

Answer (score 4):

Take a sequence of rationals $q_n$ converging to $\sqrt 2$. Then $x^{\sqrt 2}$ is defined as the limit of the sequence $x^{q_n}$. From continuity of the exponent, this limit exists, is unique, and independent of the choice of sequence. (And as you said, you already have a definition for each term in the sequence, since the powers are rational)